# Cordova Camera Plugin force orientation of camera to portrait

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I am using cordova camera plugin latest to take a photo of documents in my cordova android app. The following are the options:

```
camera.options = {
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                cameraDirection: 0,
                correctOrientation:false,
                targetWidth:2048,
                targetHeight:2048,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };
```

But when I click a photo of my document in portrait mode, the camera flips it 90 degrees and it becomes landscape. I don't want it to flip it. I want it to keep it as it is. Also, I must point out it only happens when my phone is parallel to the ground, when I am clicking a photo of a document placed on the table.

I could not find anything helpful related to this in the camera plugin repo. Can somebody help me?

Comment: There are thiousands of Android device models. Many of them do not save portrait images at all. They save landscape images regardless of device orientation, then set the EXIF `Orientation` header to tell image viewers to please rotate the image. There is nothing you can do about that, as the behavior is part of the firmware and hardware. You are welcome to examine the EXIF headers and rotate the image, though. How easy this will be in Cordova (except by altering the plugin), I cannot say.

Comment: Have you tried setting `correctOrientation:true`?

Comment: @RoadieRich I have tried that and even then the output is same.

Comment: @GauravChandra Give it a try with this combination - allowEdit : true and correctOrientation : true  Else have a look at this link - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/camera-wrong-orientation-with-android/8583/21 Hope it helps. Keep us posted

Comment: @gandhi i cannot use allowedit true as the client does not want another step in between. Also if i dont complete the edit step, the app does not get the image url back. I will try the solution in the post. But it is so stupid that cordova does not allow me to keep the orientation like i want

Comment: @Gaurav Did you tried out all the probable solutions mentioned in the link?

Comment: @Gandhi, sadly I tried everything I could and I am not able to get the image from rotating. I have given up on this now.

Comment: I can think of two possible workaround solutions: 1) You could detect the orientation of the image by checking if the width is longer than the height and then rotate the photo accordingly. 2) You could use the gyroscope plugin to detect whether the phone is laying flat and again rotate accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

I just wanna share on how I solved my issue, on why the cordova camera forces the portrait shot to landscape when rendered on HTML.

```
var options = {
       quality: 50,
       destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, //DATA_URL , FILE_URI
       sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
       encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPG,
       mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
       targetWidth: 500,
       targetHeight: 500,
       saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
       correctOrientation: true //Corrects Android orientation quirks
}
```

The property **correctOrientation** actually did not completely solved the issue. Instead I change the **encodingType** to from **PNG** to **JPG.**

Comment: In your sample code, it shows ".PNG", so it's wrong ?

Comment: JPG is not a valid property. Use JPEG instead.

Answer (score 6):

This question is a bit old but in my case setting `correctOrientation: true` in the camera options has worked. I have used [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera).

```
const cameraOptions = {
    cameraDirection: 1, 
    correctOrientation: true, 
    destinationType: 1
}

navigator.camera.getPicture( 
    function(path) {
        // preview the image in the dom
        // you need to have an <img id="img"> in your dom
        document.querySelector("#img").src = path;
    },
    function(err) {
        console.warn('an error has occured: ' + err);

    }, cameraOptions
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is still an open issue in cordova camera plugin. If none of the workarounds is helping you at this point, then you gotta wait for this [request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/167) to get resolved so that you can force the orientation lock. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes but that issue seems to dead and no work on that

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove:

```
correctOrientation:false
```

from options.